# Using TFS 2010 - How do you create a build of multiple projects into one WSP for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

I have one solution that contains many SharePoint projects. What I would like to do is configure a build in TFS that will create one WSP from a selection of projects in my solution. I am passing the MSBuild Commandline Argument /p:IsPackaging=True in the Build Definition.

For example, I may have one build named X, that builds one WSP from the output of projects 1, 2, and 3. Then, I may have another build named Y, that builds one WSP from the projects 2, 5, 7, and 8.

In the "Process" section of a build definition, when I add multiple projects under "Items to Build", it outputs a WSP for each project. Which is great, but I would like one single WSP for all projects defined in the build.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you targeting? Which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: 2010 on both SharePoint and TFS

Answer (score 2):

by using the Feature Designer you can design your Features and by using the Packaging Explorer you can define what goes in which WSP. The build is not responsible for defining this. It's your project. By default each SharePoint Project results in a single wsp. 
In TeamBuild you can easily define which projects should be builded. By using the combination of theses settings (Packaging Explorer within your projects and Build Definition for TFS 2010 builds) you can easily form up the wsp and the automatic creation of this.

As you already mentioned, IsPackaging=True is required to guarantee that wsp's are created when your BuildAgent is holding all the pre-reqs for building SharePoint 2010 projects.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts